# (JS DOM) creating new elements in divs

Tags: javascript, html, input, textarea

So, I was trying to make a web app which acts like bot which uses a the textarea element as input. While referring to the [JS DOM docs provided by W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp), I saw that my code was not working. I'm also new to JS DOM, so please forgive me if i'm the stupidest person you've ever met. (which i probably am)

**Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="https://bot.valueyu.repl.co/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
  function reply() {
    const rplyBox = document.getElementById('rplyBox')
    const input = document.getElementById('msgBox').value;
    if (input === "help") {
      const embed = document.createElement("div");
      embed.classList.add("w3-round-xxlarge", "w3-margin-top", "w3-margin-bottom", "w3-margin-right", "w3-margin-left")
      const title = document.createElement("h1")
      title.createTextNode("Help");
      const desc = document.createElement("h3")
      desc.createTextNode("All of my commands!");
      const field1 = document.createElement("h6")
      field1.createTextNode("e");
      embed.appendChild(title);
      embed.appendChild(desc);
      embed.appendChild(field1);
      rplyBox.appendChild(embed);
    }
  }
</script>

<body style="background-image: url('https://bot.valueyu.repl.co/bg.mp4'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
  <div class="main">
    <t>bot.valueyu</t>
    <p>bot.valueyu is a bot made by Aarav Saini/Valueyu. For commmands type "<span
        class="w3-text-white">help</span>".</p>
    <hr>
    <textarea class="w3-round-large w3-bar" id="msgBox"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" onClick="reply()" class="w3-round-xxlarge w3-button">Send</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-round-large" id="rplyBox">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any jsdom code here. It's used in Node, not the browser. Just use the actual DOM in the browser (which is what you're doing). I'm removing the [tag:jsdom] tag but let me know if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your code, a new text node was created using the createTextNode method, but it was not added to the desc element, which means it wouldn't be visible on the webpage.

**Note: the document has the createTextNode property and not the element that was just created**

In the corrected code below, the createTextNode method is still used to create a text node, but it is then added to the desc element using the appendChild method. This makes the text visible on the webpage as a child of the desc element.

**so the updated Js code will be:**

```js
  function reply() {
    const rplyBox = document.getElementById('rplyBox')
    const input = document.getElementById('msgBox').value;
    if (input === "help") {
    
      const embed = document.createElement("div");
      embed.classList.add("w3-round-xxlarge", "w3-margin-top", "w3-margin-bottom", "w3-margin-right", "w3-margin-left")
      
      const title = document.createElement("h1")
      title.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Help"));

      const desc = document.createElement("h3")
      desc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("All of my commands!"));

      const field1 = document.createElement("h6")
      
      field1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("e"));

      embed.appendChild(title);
      embed.appendChild(desc);
      embed.appendChild(field1);
      rplyBox.appendChild(embed);
    }
  }
```

Comment: tyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only entity who can create nodes in Javascript is the **[DOM document object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)** ([you can see here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp)), so by correcting that in your code, [it will work](https://replit.com/@JuanCastillo18/RepulsiveAbsoluteSuperuser#index.html).